# Unsure of regex for numeric which can include unit chars

Tags: regex

I have the following regex which only allows numerics

^[0-9]+$

Trouble is, I also need to allow the user to enter a decimal aspect and unit

So these would all need to be valid

123

123456789

1.25M

1.2K

1.5B

12345.53M

0.5M

If anyone can help I'd be most grateful

Comment: are numbers with a trailing or a leading decimal separator allowed?

Comment: Are decimals allowed if there are no units?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work for all your cases, and exclude all the cases that should not match?

```
^\d*\.?\d+[GMKB]?$
```

Explanation:

```
^\d*    - Start with zero or more digits
\.?     - Allow a decimal point, if there is one
\d+     - Require at least one digit (which might be after a decimal point)
[GMKB]? - Allow one of these 4 letters
$       - Don't allow any more characters after this sequence
```

Comment: Works a treat.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specified one I assume you are using perl compatible regex engine. You can use this:

```
/^([0-9]*\.)?[0-9]+(B|K|M|G)?$/
```

I also assume that numbers like `0.1` can be written like `.1`. Having the units encapsulated in capturing group `(B|K|M|G)` makes it easy to extract it from results afterwards.

You can test the regex [here](http://regex101.com/r/vQ1fH1/1)

Comment: Why not use `([BKMG])`?

Comment: Also, to capture everything, the first part should be `([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?`

Comment: To your first comment, yes it can be used too since the units all consists just of a single char. However, if we would have units allowing multiple chars my attempt would be right. That's why I always doing so... Let me think about your second comment.. mom ..

Comment: About your second comment, I don't see a logical difference between my solution and your suggested attempt. Maybe I'm overlooking something, can you give an example?

Comment: The regex in the second comment captures everything, so you can then use it in substitutions: `s/.../$1,$2\ $3byte/` or so

Comment: The question is: Would you accept something like `2000foobar`? Or would you like to specify a well defined set of allowed units? (I guess this can be only answered by the OP)

Comment: I think that for some complex units you still could use `([ZYEPTGMkhdcmunpfazy]?m|dam)` (this one's matching meters, centimeters etc.) and it would look clean and be short.

Comment: The OP only lists B, K, and M. (I'm not even sure what units those are.)

Comment: I think he means `(kilo|mega|giga)?bytes?`

Comment: Making regexes is contagious. Here's what I made just now:

`^([0-9]+|(a lot|lots) of|a (few|little)|some|no) *(((([YZEPTGMkhdcmunpfazy]?|da)(m|g|s))|(\s(yotta|zetta|exa|peta|tera|giga|mega|kilo|hecto|deca|centi|deci|milli|micro|nano|pico|femto|atto|zepto|yocto)?(metre|gram|second)s?))|((minute|hour|day|week|month|year)s?))$`  

![Regular expression visualisation](https://www.debuggex.com/i/ncxQckZu9mrSNyW1.png)